# Creating a simple color map from black to color to white in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do i create a simple colormap in matplotlib that goes from black (minimum value) to color of my choice to white (maximum value).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap` to create you own colormap. Here's a basic example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import numpy as np

# Define your intermediate color
intermediate_color = 'blue'  # This can be an RGB tuple, RGBA tuple, hex code, etc.

# Create a custom colormap
cmap = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('custom_colormap', ['black', intermediate_color, 'white'])

gradient = np.linspace(0, 1, 256).reshape(1, -1)
gradient = np.vstack((gradient, gradient))

plt.imshow(gradient, aspect='auto', cmap=cmap)
plt.axis('off')
plt.title('my custom colormap with Blue as intermediate')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Check out the documentation to learn more: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.html